# Good methods of connecting to Netezza using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, netezza

I am very new to Ruby and I'm using RUBYDEVKIT 2.1 and ANSICON 1.6
(I was given an installation guide for my workplace). I have tried googling this topic, but I can't seem to find a way to connect to Netezza using only Ruby.

The few posts I can find say to use activerecord-netezza-adapter, but doing 'gem install activerecord-netezza-adapter' tells me no valid gems found, and I don't know that I can use JRuby here at my workplace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to connect to Netezza with Ruby, use the [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) gem [ruby-odbc](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-odbc/versions/0.99997).

Your question implies some sort of native, embedded driver set in a Ruby library. Since Netezza uses ODBC, OLEDB, and JDBC for connectivity, the closest thing you'll find is something that creates JDBC strings for you on the fly. Even the gem you mentioned, [activerecord-netezza-adapter](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-netezza-adapter/versions/0.1.1-java) uses JDBC.

If you do want to use JDBC from within Ruby, use [Jruby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JDBC).

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for your response. I've looked into using ODBC but apparently my Ruby version at work is locked to 2.1.7, but I've read a few bug report that say ODBC will only work with 2.1.5 and lower.

Comment: Did you try it? I run 2.2.2p95 with no issues.